# Macro to search columns for list of specific words that may be similar to each others

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel macro that search a list of string in a column.

**For example :** let's say i'm searching for "sun" in my column.
If one cell value is "We have a beautiful sunshine", then the cell contains the string "sun" and "sun" is written next to the cell, for me to identify the matches later

**My problem is :** if, in the list of string i'm looking for, there is first "sunshine", then "sun", then the macro will first write "sunshine" next to "We have a beautiful sunshine", then it will write "sun".

It's technically correct, this is what my macro do, but it's more relevant to me to know if there's the entire word "sunshine" than just "sun".

I need to add a condition like "find if there is this string in each cell of my column, **and** if there's no other string from the list i'm looking for."

And I don't quite know where to get started..

Here is my code if it can help :

```
Sub Reperer_Ch_Caracteres()

y = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    Keyword = Range("A" & i)
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Columns(2).Find(Keyword, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not c Is Nothing And IsEmpty(Range("C" & i)) = True Then

            firstAddress = c.Address

            Do
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Keyword


            Set c = ActiveSheet.Columns(2).FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress

        End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to work out the logic, and then how to structure it so that you can codify it. Perhaps you have a list of search terms in decreasing order of priority and then you look for each and once one is found you stop (?)

Comment: What is the maximum number of expected occurences of the keyword in the string? If it is limited you might hard-code for example 5 possible matches to enter values in C,D,E,F and G

Comment: IF Keyword LIKE " * listObject * " THEN c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Keyword. This seems to possibly solve the issue? I really only glanced at your code but it seems the like operator should be super handy dandy here